# Handle invalid Body when receiving Post Request in Web Api

Tags: c#, json, post, asp.net-web-api

I have a third party that will be sending Post requests to a Web Api service I am making.

I have a function like

```
public returnObject PostFromThirdPartyObject(ThirdPartyObject JSONobj)
{
    // Process Object
    return returnObject;
}
```

This is working fine when I send the correct object.

Problem is when an invalid object gets sent, the `ThirdPartyObject` fills with nulls.

I want to be able to capture the invalid object so I can log and diagnose the issue because I don't trust the third party specification.

How can I handle a Post body that doesn't match the expected type?

---

Edit: The Code used to test in case that needs to be changed

```
string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ThirdPartyObject);
var cfReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
cfReq.ContentType = "application/json";
cfReq.Method = "Post";
cfReq.ContentLength = body.Length;
var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
var stream = cfReq.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(byteArray, 0, body.Length);

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)cfReq.GetResponse();
var stringResponse = string.Empty;
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    stringResponse = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

---

EDIT 2: Really poor workaround using an object, hopefully someone can post a more correct way

```
public Status PostFromThirdPartyObject([FromBody] object sObject)
{
    ThirdPartyObject obj = null;
    string sRequest = null;
    try
    {
        sRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sObject);
        LogRequest(sRequest);
        var setting = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        setting.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
        obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ThirdPartyObject>(sRequest, setting);
    }
    catch
    {
        if (sObject != null)
        {
            return Error
        }
        else
        {
            return NullError
        }
    }
    return processThirdPartyObject(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with ModelState.IsValid():

```
public returnObject PostFromThirdPartyObject([FromBody] ThirdPartyObject JSONobj)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid()) {
        // Do someting
    }
    // Process Object
    return returnObject;
}
```

Comment: I can get this to tell me if the object is invalid, but this does not give the actual data passed in to the service.

Comment: You could use `Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` to see what is the invalid content.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Shaukat Sarwar's answer, you can access the body from the `HttpContext`.

```
public returnObject PostFromThirdPartyObject(ThirdPartyObject JSONobj)
{
    var content = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream /*, Encoding here if necessary */)
                    .ReadToEnd();

    // Process Object
    return returnObject;
}
```

Remember to use the appropriate encoding in the `StreamReader` (UTF8, most likely).

You might also want to take a look at `ModelState.IsValid`, as another answer said. Just mark all required properties in your model as `[Required]` (otherwise `ModelState.IsValid` will always be true) and get the raw content of the invalid request there to save it.

```
public returnObject PostFromThirdPartyObject(ThirdPartyObject JSONobj)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var content = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream /*, Encoding here if necessary */)
                .ReadToEnd();

        // Do something with the raw content here

        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    // Process Object
    return returnObject;
}
```

See also: [Model Validation in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

There will be some good options but for now, what you can do is expect stream as input and read it in string. you have exactly what your client has posted in that string. you can than deserialized that string into the ThirdPartyObject using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ThirdPartyObject>(inpString)`

your function could be like:

```
public returnObject PostFromThirdPartyObject(Stream jsonStream)
{
        string sRequest = String.Empty;
        StreamReader stmRequest = new StreamReader(input, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        sRequest = stmRequest.ReadToEnd();
        ThirdPartyObject obj = null;

        try{
            obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ThirdPartyObject>(sRequest)
           }
        catch
        {
           //you have the object posted by your client in sRequest
           //do whatever you want
        }

    // obj is your object to process
    // Process Object
    return returnObject;
}
```

your client does not need to change anything on its end.

Comment: I tried your solution, looks like the jsonSteam is null. Could be the test code, edited my post with that. Also, assumed "StreamReader(input..." should be "StreamReader(jsonStream..."

Comment: sorry for being late. and that typo mistake too. is your method POST? because it will work for POST only